# Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of products

```
public class Product {

   public Product() { }

   public string ProductCode {get; set;}
   public decimal Price {get; set; }
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to group the collection based on the product code and return an object containing the name, the number or products for each code and the total price for each product.

```
public class ResultLine{

   public ResultLine() { }

   public string ProductName {get; set;}
   public string Price {get; set; }
   public string Quantity {get; set;}
}
```

So I use a GroupBy to group by ProductCode, then I calculate the sum and also count the number of records for each product code.

This is what I have so far:

```
List<Product> Lines = LoadProducts();    
List<ResultLine> result = Lines
                .GroupBy(l => l.ProductCode)
                .SelectMany(cl => cl.Select(
                    csLine => new ResultLine
                    {
                        ProductName =csLine.Name,
                        Quantity = cl.Count().ToString(),
                        Price = cl.Sum(c => c.Price).ToString(),
                    })).ToList<ResultLine>();
```

**For some reason, the sum is done correctly but the count is always 1.**

Sampe data:

```
List<CartLine> Lines = new List<CartLine>();
            Lines.Add(new CartLine() { ProductCode = "p1", Price = 6.5M, Name = "Product1" });
            Lines.Add(new CartLine() { ProductCode = "p1", Price = 6.5M, Name = "Product1" });
            Lines.Add(new CartLine() { ProductCode = "p2", Price = 12M, Name = "Product2" });
```

Result with sample data:

```
Product1: count 1   - Price:13 (2x6.5)
Product2: count 1   - Price:12 (1x12)
```

Product 1 should have count = 2!

I tried to simulate this in a simple console application but there i got the following result:

```
Product1: count 2   - Price:13 (2x6.5)
Product1: count 2   - Price:13 (2x6.5)
Product2: count 1   - Price:12 (1x12)
```

Product1: should only be listed once...
The code for the above can be found on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/cNHTBSie

Answer (score 372, accepted):

I don't understand where the first "result with sample data" is coming from, but the problem in the console app is that you're using `SelectMany` to look at *each item in each group*.

I think you just want:

```
List<ResultLine> result = Lines
    .GroupBy(l => l.ProductCode)
    .Select(cl => new ResultLine
            {
                ProductName = cl.First().Name,
                Quantity = cl.Count().ToString(),
                Price = cl.Sum(c => c.Price).ToString(),
            }).ToList();
```

The use of `First()` here to get the product name assumes that every product with the same product code has the same product name. As noted in comments, you could group by product name as well as product code, which will give the same results if the name is always the same for any given code, but apparently generates better SQL in EF.

I'd also suggest that you should change the `Quantity` and `Price` properties to be `int` and `decimal` types respectively - why use a string property for data which is clearly not textual?

Comment: Ok my console app is working. Thanks for point me out to use First() and leave out SelectMany. The ResultLine is actually a ViewModel. The price will get formatted with currency sign. That's why I need it to be a string. But i could change quantity to int.. I'll see now if this may also help for my website. I'll let you know.

Comment: @ThdK: No, you should keep `Price` as a decimal too, and then change how you format it. Keep the data representation clean, and only change to a presentation view at the last possible moment.

Comment: Why not to Group by ProductCode and Name? Something like that: .GroupBy(l => new{l.ProductCode, l.Name}) and use ProductName = c.Key.Name,

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov: Yes, that's another option, certainly.

Comment: Ok, it seems my collection was actually a wrapper around the real collection.. Shoot me.. Good thing is, I practiced some Linq today :)

Comment: This post gets high results when searching for information on aggregate results using group by, but I wanted to offer a word of caution when using this against EntityFramework. The First/FirstOrDefault will cause EF to generate nested selects which can have serious performance implications.  Kirill's suggestion of using GroupBy generates the SQL one would expect.

Comment: @ShaneH: Thanks, will add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 42):

The following query works. It uses each group to do the select instead of `SelectMany`. `SelectMany` works on each element from each collection. For example, in your query you have a result of 2 collections. `SelectMany` gets all the results, a total of 3, instead of each collection. The following code works on each `IGrouping` in the select portion to get your aggregate operations working correctly.

```
var results = from line in Lines
              group line by line.ProductCode into g
              select new ResultLine {
                ProductName = g.First().Name,
                Price = g.Sum(pc => pc.Price).ToString(),
                Quantity = g.Count().ToString(),
              };
```

Answer (score 7):

sometimes you need to select some fields by `FirstOrDefault()` or `singleOrDefault()` you can use the below query:

```
List<ResultLine> result = Lines
    .GroupBy(l => l.ProductCode)
    .Select(cl => new Models.ResultLine
            {
                ProductName = cl.select(x=>x.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                Quantity = cl.Count().ToString(),
                Price = cl.Sum(c => c.Price).ToString(),
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: can you please explain why sometimes i need to use `FirstOrDefault() or `singleOrDefault()` ?

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde First() and FirstOrDefault() gets the first object in a series, whereas Single() and SingleOrDefault() expects only 1 from the result. If Single() and SingleOrDefault()sees that there are more than 1 object in a result set or as a result of the provided argument, it will throw an exception. On usage, you use the former when you only want, maybe a sample of a series and the other objects are not important to you, whereas you use the latter if you are only expecting one object and do something if there are more than one result, like log the error.