# Summing same elements in List<>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

have some beginner problems with c#/entityFramework...the shown tables are more bigger and I don't know the 'Name' value in the tables...

I have a Table tblFruits like this:

```
**tblFruits     
ID  Name    Amount (kg)**
1   apple   10
2   orange  20
3   orange  30
4   lemon   40
5   apple   50
6   orange  60
```

and I want show the same fruit just one time and summing the amount of the same fruits.

This is the output:

```
**tblFruitsTotal        
ID  Name    Amount(kg)**
1   apple   60
2   orange  110
3   lemon   40
```

I need a List object to bind it ro my datagrid in xaml..whats the best way? please help

Comment: You need to `GroupBy` the name

Comment: Similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (Fruits item in tblFruits.GroupBy(x => x.Name))
{
    tblFruitsTotal.Add(new Fruits() 
    { 
        ID = tblFruitsTotal.Any() ? tblFruitsTotal.Max(x=>x.ID) + 1 : 1,
        Name = item.First().Name, 
        Amount = item.Sum(x => x.Amount) 
    });
}
```

And be sure to include 'using System.Linq;'

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
public class Fruit
    {

        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var fruits = new List<Fruit>
            {
                new Fruit {Name = "Apple", Quantity = 10},
                new Fruit {Name = "Orange", Quantity = 20},
                new Fruit {Name = "Orange", Quantity = 60},
                new Fruit {Name = "Apple", Quantity = 50}
            };


            var groupedFruit = fruits.GroupBy(l => l.Name)
                          .Select(lg =>
                                new
                                {
                                    Name = lg.Key,
                                    TotalQuantity = lg.Sum(q => q.Quantity)
                                });

            foreach (var fruit in groupedFruit)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fruit: {0} : Quantity: {1}", 
                    fruit.Name, fruit.TotalQuantity);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
```

I have added the code to a console application so you get the idea how it works.

Answer (score -2):

Below will accumalate all the values, make them unique and incrememnt the amounts.

```
Dictionary<string, value> _newTable = new Dictionary<string, value>();
foreach (var fruit in tblFruits) {
    if (!_newTable.contains(fruit.name)) {
        _newTable.Add(fruit.name, 0);
    }

    _newTable[fruit.name] += fruit.amount;
}
```

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it is enumerable and collection. So is a list and should be easily bindable to xaml.

Comment: there is an "else" missing

Comment: Because when it doesn't exist you are adding the amount twice for the initial occurence

Comment: I did this on the fly in a text editor as a quick solution, there isn't an else missing, I just shouldn't add the `fuit.amount` it should just be 0