# Show record using entity framework or linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have record

```
voucher_id    voucher_Date    Voucher_type     Total

1              1/2/2015        sale            10000

2              1/2/2015        sale            15000

3              1/2/2015       purchase         5000

4              25/2/2015       sale            10000
```

how to display data in date wise and calculate as,

```
Voucher_Date     Sale         Purchase

1/2/2015          25000        5000

25/2/2015         10000
```

Comment: you can do it by using GroupBy

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count

Comment: I will say it isn't duplicated, because here you can/should do a conditional sum, twice... Sale = ...Sum(x => x.Voucher_type == Sale ? Total : 0), Purchase = ...Sum(x => x.Voucher_type == Purchase ? Total : 0). Not sure if EF supports this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be something like:

```
var res = from x in MyTable
          group x by x.voucher_Date into y
          select new 
          { 
              Voucher_Date = y.Voucher_Date, 
              Sale = y.Sum(z => z.Voucher_type == "sale" ? z.Total : 0),
              Purchase = y.Sum(z => z.Voucher_type == "purchase" ? z.Total : 0),
          }
```

Note that I'm not sure if EF supports the form of `Sum` I have used.

The equivalent SQL query should be:

```
SELECT Voucher_Date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Voucher_type = 'sale' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) Sale,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Voucher_type = 'purchase' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) Purchase
       FROM MyTable
       GROUP BY voucher_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to group records on `Voucher_Date` and then filter from each go up on basis of `Voucher_Type` that it is `sale` or `purchase`:

```
var result = from v in db.Vouchers
             group v by v.Voucher_Date into g
             select new
                 {
                  Date = g.Key,
                  Sale = g.Where(x=>x.Voucher_Type == "sale").Sum(y=y.Total),
                  Purchase = g.Where(x=>x.Voucher_Type == "purchase").Sum(x=>x.Total)
                 }
```