# I need to create an interface in c# and a method to load a list of the interface

Tags: c#, linq, interface, lambda

Having the two class/inteface below:

```
[Schema("dbo")]
[Alias("Team")]
public class Team : IHasId<int>
{
    [Alias("TeamId"), AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string TeamName { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public int DivisionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public interface ITotal
{
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    Team Team { get; set; }
    Account Account { get; set; }
    double Total { get; set; }
}

public class Total: ITotal
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public Team Team {get; set;}
    public Account {get; set;}
    public double Total {get; set;}
}
```

I am trying to create a default method to return a sum of total by Team id, I am not very familiar using interfaces, so I am not sure if what I did was the best solution, also should I use something like ITotalCollection instead of List ?

```
public class QueryTotalCollection: List<Total>
{
    public List<Total> GetTotalByTeam()
    {
```

> ```
>         // todo: I need to return here the same object. However,
>         // grouping by Team and the Sum of .Total (in this case the
>         // property "Account" will return null as I am grouping by Team.
>         // for instance: select Date, Team, null as Account, sum(Total)
>         //               group by Date, Team
>         // return this.GroupBy(x => x.Team.Id)...
> ```

```
    }
}
```

The method above is not working, how can I do this? I want to return a
sum of ITotal.Total grouped by Team.Id

Comment: You want the sum grouped by total, but yet you return a `double` from your method. How would you know which teams sum it is that returned?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I did it wrong, you are right.. I need to return a ITotal with the list of Teams not repeated and the totals for each one

Comment: Did you get the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Not Yet, I wrote again my problem... @YuvalItzchakov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is basic misuse of interfaces and what you think it does. First of all if you want to create a class that does return a sum of total, then do just that. You need no interfaces for that.

But if you have multiple classes (at least two) that will implement ITotal interface, then I would recommend use helper method, as it is what you need (you need helper method right?). Info about [extending class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24948/Three-Ways-To-Extend-A-Class). Sample code:

```
public static class TeamSelectHeleper
{
    public static double GetTotalByTeam(this List<ITotal> myList)
    {
        // TODO Sum wont work this way - fix it
        //return myList.GroupBy(x => x.Team.Id).Sum(s => s.Total);

        // If you need just a sum, then just sum it.
        // but if you need group results,
        // then you can just return on number when there is a list
        return myList.Sum(s => s.Total);
    }
}
```

You can then apply this method to any list containing ITotal.
And group by doesn't work the way you think it does. Use [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count) or [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea)

Comment: Why are you posting a method which doesn't compile? If you wish to show Extension Methods as an example, either don't post code inside the method at all, or post compiling code. Writing *"TODO: Fix this doesn't actually work"* doesn't help.

Comment: Ok. I will change I will be more specific

Comment: There is one problem with this group by, why I posted it this way - because I have no idea what author wants - it either doesn't need group by, either needs to return not a single number, but a something like dictionary. Sorry if this was misleading. Your remark is noted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly implement that `ITotal` interface with one of your classes which will include all the declared methods of that interface. Something like this :

```
public class QueryTotalCollection: ITotal
{
    public double Total()
    {
        //your actual method body code.
    }
}
```

Also, you might want to read some basic stuff about [Interfaces](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CGgQFjAL&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F87d83y5b.aspx&ei=EUpQVYybCYKKuwTL-4GYDQ&usg=AFQjCNEVMhzqShFFzLSkIRtwq6PE07SI-A&sig2=LwxZTdc5NOKBNx-Ffxqorw&bvm=bv.92885102,d.c2E) and how they are used and implemented. That should help you through this.

Hope this helps.