# C# filter the datatable and calculate

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

I am working on a C# code with a data table.

The table is like:

### ID  area  day1  day2  day3 day4

### a     1    0.1   0.1   0.1  0.1

### b     1    0.1   0.1   0.1  0.1

### c     1    0.1   0.1   0.1  0.1

### d     2    0.1   0.1   0.1  0.1

### e     2    0.1   0.1   0.1  0.1

I want to filter the datatable with area code and sum the rows in the same area together? What will be a good way to realize this function?

Comment: Look at WHERE (filtering) and SUM. Write some code. Post that code if you're still stuck (pointing out exactly where you are stuck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward. Filter by Area code, group by area and then Sum up all days:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Area", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Day1", typeof(double));
table.Columns.Add("Day2", typeof(double));
table.Columns.Add("Day3", typeof(double));
table.Columns.Add("Day4", typeof(double));

table.Rows.Add("a", 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
table.Rows.Add("b", 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
table.Rows.Add("c", 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
table.Rows.Add("d", 2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
table.Rows.Add("e", 2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1);

var result = table.AsEnumerable().Where (t => t.Field<int>("Area") == 1)
                                 .GroupBy (t => t.Field<int>("Area"))
                                 .Select(x => new {
                                    Area = x.Key,
                                    Day1 = x.Sum (y => y.Field<double>("Day1")),
                                    Day2 = x.Sum (y => y.Field<double>("Day2")),
                                    Day3 = x.Sum (y => y.Field<double>("Day3")),
                                    Day4 = x.Sum (y => y.Field<double>("Day4"))
                                 });
result.Dump();
```

Output:

[image]

Linqpad source: http://share.linqpad.net/fqwflw.linq

References:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415(v=vs.110).aspx
- [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works!

Comment: But for a very large table about 1000 rows and 4000 columns,  is there a good way to do the calculation?

Comment: Why don't you try it out