# Merge two collections and sum the fields for duplicate items

Tags: c#

I have a two collections:

```
public interface ISomeNeededInterface
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    Guid Guid { get; set; }
}

public class Order : ISomeNeededInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}

public class SalesOrder
{   
  public string Name { get { return Item.Name;} }
  public double Price { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
  private ISomeNeededInterface Item { get; private set; }

  public SalesOrder(ISomeNeededInterface _item)
  {
    Item = _item;
    Price = _item.Pricce;
    Quantity = _item.Quantity;
  }   
}

List<SalesOrder> Orders1 = new List<SalesOrder>()
  {
     new SalesOrder(new Order {"Ballon1", Guid.NewGuid();}, 2.54, 1),
     new SalesOrder(new Order {"Ballon2", Guid.NewGuid();}, 2.54, 1),
  };

List<SalesOrder> Orders2 = new List<SalesOrder>()
  {
     new SalesOrder(new Order {"Ballon1", Guid.NewGuid();}, 2.54, 2),
     new SalesOrder(new Order {"Ball", Guid.NewGuid();}, 4.52, 1)
  };
```

How to merge two collections into one, as well as to merge those elements that have coincided "Name" fields? At the same time, for the elements, merged names must sum of the field "Quantity". At the end must be

```
List<SalesOrder> SummOrders = {"Ballon1", 2.54, 3, SOME_Item; "Ballon2", 2.54, 1, SOME_Item ;  "Ball", 4.52, 1, SOME_Item }
```

Edited: need clarify for simple question?? Ok, there is more real "edited"

Comment: Have you tried something? What results did you get? We're not here ready to do your job, you gotta try by yourself before asking

Comment: What happens when the price doesn't match? Have you tried GroupBy?

Comment: I did this: find the matching in the two collections on certain properties. Create collection of them and summed their fields. Of theese two collections (in post above)  I remove the elements of the duplicate collection. Combine all three collections. But I think that it is too ... wrong)))

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Concat`, `GroupBy` and `Sum`:

```
List<SalesOrder> merged = Order1.Concat(Orders2)
    .GroupBy(so => so.Name)
    .Select(g => new SalesOrder(g.Key, g.First().Price, g.Sum(so => so.Quantity)))
    .ToList();
```

Consider that the `Name` could be equal but it has a different `Price`, so it's actually a different product. Then you could group by an anonymous type containing both properties (ideally you use a unique identifier):

```
List<SalesOrder> merged = Order1.Concat(Orders2)
    .GroupBy(so => new { so.Name, so.Price })
    .Select(g => new SalesOrder(g.Key.Name, g.Key.Price, g.Sum(so => so.Quantity)))
    .ToList();
```