# Dictionary and condition

Tags: asp.net, .net, dictionary, conditional-statements

I have been working on an assignment in which I have to upload some records from a file to Dictionary and manipulate.

Actually file have number of record with same invoice number and different tax values and I have to add all those values and make it only one invoice

**what I'm trying to do** 
I'm passing values from a foreach loop to a function which check if the dictionary is empty so it will simply add first record and on second call it will check weather any record in dictionary have same invoice number so it will sum and update current tax value to one already added,

**what I'm getting**
when I pass 2nd value (and so on) the previous value of last entry in dictionary some how update itself with current value before even comparing which I don't want.

```
public jd_records jd  = new jd_records();        
Dictionary<int, jd_records> jdValues = new Dictionary<int, jd_records>();

//Calling values with loop while jd is a publicly declared object of class jd_records

            foreach (DataRow dr in jddt.Rows)
            {
                //jd_records jdPass = new jd_records();                    
                jd.supplierName = dr["Supplier"].ToString();
                jd.supplierNTN = dr["Supplier NTN"].ToString();
                jd.invoiceNo = dr["JDE Invoice Number"].ToString();
                jd.invoiceDate = DateTime.Parse(dr["JDE Invoice Date"].ToString());

                if (dr["Taxable Amount"].ToString().Equals(""))
                { jd.taxable = 0; }
                else
                { jd.taxable = float.Parse(dr["Taxable Amount"].ToString()); }


                if (dr["Tax To Pay"].ToString().Equals(""))
                { jd.tax = 0; }
                else
                { jd.tax = float.Parse(dr["Tax To Pay"].ToString()); }

                jdRecordCheck();

            }
```

**called function**

```
 public void jdRecordCheck()
    {
        if (jdValues.Count < 1)
        {
            jdValues.Add(0, jd);
        }
        else //previous record values (at key 0) changes to new jd value when come to this else part on execution
        {

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int,jd_records> jdVal  in jdValues)
            {
                if ((jdVal.Value.supplierNTN.Equals(jd.supplierNTN)) && (jdVal.Value.invoiceNo.Equals(jd.invoiceNo)))
                {
                    jdVal.Value.tax = jdVal.Value.tax + jd.tax;
                    jdVal.Value.taxable = jdVal.Value.taxable + jd.taxable;

                    jdValues[jdVal.Key] = jdVal.Value;

                }                    
                else
                {
                    jdValues.Add(jdVal.Key + 1, jd);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I'll be very thankful if anyone helps.

Comment: `jd` always points to the same instance, so you're updating the properties of an existing object and adding the same reference to the dictionary multiple times.  You should create a new `jd_records` object with each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: so it means in dictionary objects are stored by reference and not by value ?

Comment: Well, classes are value types, so their value _is_ a reference.  value types (ints, dates, etc) are value types, so what's stored is the actual value.  That's different than being "stored by reference".

Comment: I just realized my comment above is wrong. Classes are _reference types_, so their value is a reference.

Comment: by the way Mr. @DStanley I appreciate your suggestion  as my program is working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me this would be much easier to do with [Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count), which contains functions for grouping and summing.

```
List<jd_records> result = jddt.Rows
    .GroupBy(jd => jd.invoiceNo)
    .Select(jd => new jd_records
        {
            invoiceNo = jd.invoiceNo,
            totalTax = jd.Sum(d => d.tax)
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Actually I have first tried with List<T> but I realize that its easy to put objects in to the List<> and not when you extract them as List don't have function get(i) in C# like we have in java for ArrayList.