# c# list find duplicate update multiple lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have 3 lists `lstTicketType`, `lstQuantity` `lstAmount`. I am trying to merge ticket types and update the other two lists accordingly

The data is as follows

```
lstTicketType | lstQuantity | lstAmount
---------------------------------------
Standard      |     1       |   8:5
Standard      |     1       |   8.5
Student       |     1       |   6.5
Student       |     1       |   6.5
Senior        |     1       |    4
```

I am able to find the duplicates by using

```
      var query = lstTicketType.GroupBy(x => x)
      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
      .Select(y => new { Counter = y.Count() })
      .ToList();
```

how do i update the list so that it looks like

```
lstTicketType | lstQuantity | lstAmount
---------------------------------------
Standard      |     2       |    17
Student       |     2       |    13
Senior        |     1       |    4
```

Comment: Hint: Use `Sum()` function to sum `lstAmount`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using "Sum". Don't rely on one my answer and try to write your own code to understand how it works. Otherwise, you will never know how to code. This is my reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522841/1554116

```
internal class Ticket
{
    public string TicketType { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Ticket>();
        list.Add(new Ticket() { TicketType = "Standard", Quantity = 1, Amount = 8.5m });
        list.Add(new Ticket() { TicketType = "Standard", Quantity = 1, Amount = 8.5m });
        list.Add(new Ticket() { TicketType = "Student", Quantity = 1, Amount = 6.5m });
        list.Add(new Ticket() { TicketType = "Student", Quantity = 1, Amount = 6.5m });
        list.Add(new Ticket() { TicketType = "Senior", Quantity = 1, Amount = 4m });

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"TicketType: {item.TicketType}, Quantity: {item.Quantity}, Amount: {item.Amount}");
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");

        list = list.GroupBy(x => x.TicketType).Select(x => new Ticket()
        {
            TicketType = x.First().TicketType,
            Quantity = x.Sum(y => y.Quantity),
            Amount = x.Sum(y => y.Amount)
        }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"TicketType: {item.TicketType}, Quantity: {item.Quantity}, Amount: {item.Amount}");
        }

        System.Console.Read();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Ticket> tickets = new List<Ticket>()
            {
                new Ticket(){
                    TicketType="Standard",
                    Quantity =1,
                    Amout= 8.5M
                },
                new Ticket(){
                    TicketType="Standard",
                    Quantity =1,
                    Amout= 8.5M
                },
                new Ticket(){
                    TicketType="Student",
                    Quantity =1,
                    Amout= 6.5M
                },
                new Ticket(){
                    TicketType="Student",
                    Quantity =1,
                    Amout= 6.5M
                },
                new Ticket(){
                    TicketType="Senior",
                    Quantity =1,
                    Amout=4M
                },
            };

            var groupTicket = tickets.GroupBy(p => p.TicketType).Select(t => new
            {
                TicketType = t.Key,
                Quantity = t.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                Amount = t.Sum(x => x.Amout)
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

hi your answer is the under code

```
List<string> lstTicketType = new List<string>() { "Standard", "Standard", "Student", "Student", "Senior" };
        List<int> lstQuantity = new List<int>() { 1,1,1,1,1};
        List<double> lstAmount = new List<double>() {8.5 , 8.5 , 6.5 , 6.5 ,4};

        List<mergeClass> LstMC = new List<mergeClass>();

        for (int i = 0; i < lstTicketType.Count(); i++)
        {
            mergeClass NewMC = new mergeClass(lstTicketType[i], lstQuantity[i], lstAmount[i]);
            LstMC.Add(NewMC);
        }
        var query=LstMC.GroupBy(q=>q.TicketType)
                    .Select(q=>new{TicketType=q.First().TicketType,
                                    Quantity=q.Sum(a=>a.Quantity),
                                    Amount=q.Sum(a=>a.Amount)
                    }).ToList();
```

and you must create under class in your project

```
 public class mergeClass
{
    public string TicketType { set; get; }
    public int Quantity { set; get; }
    public double Amount { set; get; }
    public mergeClass(string T, int Q, double A)
    {
        TicketType = T;
        Quantity = Q;
        Amount = A;
    }

}
```