# Linq Query Return Duplicate Record From Sql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, angularjs, sql-server, linq

I am trying to join three linq queries into single query and display the records into an angular js application. But the problem is when I enter the account number and click the submit button, it also displays the duplicate record.

Here is the Linq Query:

```
public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
{
    var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
    using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
    {
        var CombinedQuery = (from x in context.Current_Account_Deposit
                             join y in context.Current_Account_Withdraw on x.Account_Number equals y.Account_Number
                             join z in context.Current_Account_Details on y.Account_Number equals z.Account_Number
                             where x.Account_Number == accountNumber
                             select new
                             {
                                 x.Account_Number,
                                 x.Amount,
                                 Amount1 = y.Amount,
                                 z.Account_Balance,
                             }).ToList();

        var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(CombinedQuery); // return JSON string
    }
}
```

Some people suggest me on this link ..
http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1108/linq-inner-join-left-outer-join-on-two-lists-in-c-with-example
Here is the database record screenshot:

[image]

Here is the screen shot when i clicked the button with account number and Linq query also display the duplicate record. [image]
[image]

Comment: Because your `Current_Account_Withdraw` has two records for 15, and three records for 16. That's how joins work, they are Cartesian products.

Comment: i know . how can i avoid its ?

Comment: What are you trying to display? If you wanted the total withdrawals for a day, you would SUM() the column. Your screenshot makes it appear as though your transaction dates are some type of text format, not a date. You need to update the question with your desired outcome, what is being displayed makes perfect sense. I would expect to see a one-to-many relation between an account and transactions.

Comment: I want display transaction record and avoid the duplicate record which is displaying it now . you are right the total as well

Comment: Try looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count

Comment: please tell me how can i avoid the duplication record .Instead of showing duplicate record i want to display empty cell

Comment: I think this is about displaying data and multiple relational.
so, you should make this : account_number, list_of_transaction.
let's say you will have ReturnClass of
{
   Current_Account_Details detail {get;set;}
   List<Current_Account_Withdraw> listofwithdraw {get;set;}
   List<Current_Account_Deposit> listofdeposit {get;set;}
}

Comment: @ArdiArdianto can you please post your answer i can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can use this concept of class

```
ReturnClass 
{ 
     Current_Account_Details detail {get;set;} 
     List<Current_Account_Withdraw> listofwithdraw {get;set;}
     List<Current_Account_Deposit> listofdeposit {get;set;} }
}
```

Example : (code may not working :D )
I'll use lambda

```
    context.Current_Account_Details.Select(x => new
   {
       x.Account_Number,
       detail = x,
       listofwithdraw = x.Current_Account_Withdraw.ToList(),
       listofdeposit = x.Current_Account_Deposit.ToList()
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: some user suggest me to use left outer join to avoid the duplicate record .

Comment: maybe you should share , using excel, for example,
account number 15 and its expected result (with amount)

Comment: MyDBDataContext sqlObj = new MyDBDataContext();

var employees = from emps in sqlObj.tblEmployees

                join de in sqlObj.tblDepartments on emps.DepartmentID equals de.DepartmentID into dep from dept in dep.DefaultIfEmpty()

                select new

                {

                    emps.EmployeeID,

                    emps.EmployeeName,

                    emps.Salary,

                    dept.DepartmentName

                };

Comment: check this answer ?

Comment: check this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause . 
and see part : Group Join . 
and as you see, there is "Products" , means list of product.
1 category , multi products.
as yours 1 account_detail, multi transactions

Comment: Thanks you very much