# Add Sum Function in your LINQ Query in MVC Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, group-by, sum

I am trying to `GroupBy` records and everything is working perfectly, except the Price. I don't know how to use `SUM` function in my `GroupBy` Clause. I searched on the internet but no solution matched my situation. Some records can have unit price `null`. Following is my code:

```
List<AssingingJob> Records = new List<AssingingJob>();

var Job_Ids = db.Jobs.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

Records.AddRange(db.AssingingJob.Where(x => 
                                      Job_Ids.Contains(x.JobId))
                                      .ToList()
                                      .GroupBy(x => new { 
                                                    x.ProjectId,
                                                    x.JobId 
                                              }).Select(x => x.First()));
```

I have created `ViewModel` in which I am assigning records which I am getting through looping each record.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count) solution, but it is not helpful in my case. They are saving values in `ViewModel` and unit price in not `Null`.

Comment: Try to use .Sum(x => x.Price ?? 0)

Comment: Should I use it after group by ? @cloudikka