# using linq to get sum and distinct column data from data table using c#

Tags: c#, linq

My query is similar with little extra requirement

```
SO         CTN  QTY  WT     CBM     DATE
----------------------------------------------
CGP3941410  1    77   8.96  0.07    28-Mar-18
CGP3941410  2   133  17.93  0.14    28-Mar-18
CGP3941411  2   123  17.93  0.14    28-Mar-18
CGP3941411  1    58   8.97  0.07    28-Mar-18
CGP3941411  1     2   8.97  0.07    28-Mar-18
```

I want distinct `SO` and `DATE` and `sum(CTN)`, `sum(WT)`, `sum(CBM)` for same `SO` numbers in datatable. Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: BTW, try grouping.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample input and expected outputs based on those inputs.

Comment: the question is repeated before and your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(dr => Convert.ToString(dr["DATE"]))
        .Select(g => new
        {
                DATE = g.Key,
                TotalCTN = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x["CTN"])),
                TotalWT = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x["WT"])),
                TotalCBM = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x["CBM"])),
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide some text describing what the code does.