# ASP NET CORE Entity Framework Select with GroupBy Id

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I build a service to call query like this

```
select quotaId, sum(quota)
From leaveQuota
group by quotaId
```

I getting problem in sum and group. How to do it in Entity Framework
i tried this

```
public async Task<List<LeaveTypeModel>> GetLeaveQuota(string employeeId)
{
  var leaveQuota = await DB.EmployeeLeaveQuota
    .Where(Q => Q.EmployeeId == employeeId && Q.ValidUntil >= DateTime.UtcNow)
    .Select(Q => new LeaveTypeModel
    {
        EmployeeLeaveQuotaTypeId = Q.EmployeeLeaveQuotaTypeId,
        QuotaDays = Q.QuotaDays
    })
    .ToListAsync();

    return leaveQuota;
  }
```

my model

```
public class LeaveTypeModel
{
    public int EmployeeLeaveQuotaTypeId { set; get; }
    public int QuotaDays { set; get; }
}
```

if i use `.GroupBy` i cant return it as my model and i have no idea to sum my quotadays column

i know it is a basic query, but i'm not familiar yet with entity framework and asp.net core to return its data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var leaveQuota = await DB.EmployeeLeaveQuota
    .Where(Q => Q.EmployeeId == employeeId && Q.ValidUntil >= DateTime.UtcNow)
    .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeLeaveQuotaTypeId).Select(x => 
    new LeaveTypeModel
    {
        EmployeeLeaveQuotaTypeId = x.Key,
        QuotaDays = x.Sum(y => y.QuotaDays)
    }).ToListAsync();
```