# How can I merge time entries into a single row for a weekly report?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I'm working on a time report for a ticketing system. Each tickets time is tracked per employee on a sub-table.

Raw Table Data

[image: Raw Table Data]

How can I return a weeks worth of time so that if you worked on a ticket on multiple dates it does not return multiple records? Group by Ticket maybe? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around merging the rows into a single record.

```
    Dim Today As DateTime = DateTime.Today
    Dim startOfWeek As DateTime = Today.AddDays(-1 * Today.DayOfWeek)
    Dim endOfWeek As DateTime = startOfWeek.AddDays(7)

    Dim RepeaterMyTimeDataThisWeek = (From t In db.Ticket_Times
                                      Where t.EmployeeID= EmployeeID AndAlso t.Date >= startOfWeek AndAlso t.Date < endOfWeek).ToArray()
```

[image: Current repeater display]

Missing code to group and organize the data.

```
    Dim results = RepeaterMyTimeDataThisWeek.GroupBy(Function(z) z.TicketID).[Select](Function(s) New With {
        .Ticket = s.First().Ticket,
        .Monday = s.Where(Function(c) c.Date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday).Sum(Function(c) c.Hours),
        .Tuesday = s.Where(Function(c) c.Date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday).Sum(Function(c) c.Hours),
        .Wednesday = s.Where(Function(c) c.Date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Wednesday).Sum(Function(c) c.Hours),
        .Thursday = s.Where(Function(c) c.Date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Thursday).Sum(Function(c) c.Hours),
        .Friday = s.Where(Function(c) c.Date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday).Sum(Function(c) c.Hours),
        .Saturday = s.Where(Function(c) c.Date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday).Sum(Function(c) c.Hours),
        .Sunday = s.Where(Function(c) c.Date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday).Sum(Function(c) c.Hours)
    })
```

Comment: So you want a overview per week. In this case #1284 = 0.5?

Comment: I want a single 1284 row with data in the column for Tuesday and Wednesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using GroupBy followd by Sum. An example in C#.

```
var x = new List<TicketTimes> {
    new TicketTimes{Ticket = "1284", Monday=1, Tuesday=0},
    new TicketTimes{Ticket = "1284", Monday=0.5f, Tuesday=1},
    new TicketTimes{Ticket = "251", Monday=1, Tuesday=0},
    new TicketTimes{Ticket = "6", Monday=1, Tuesday=0},

};

var results = x.GroupBy(z => z.Ticket)
 .Select(s => new TicketTimes {
    Ticket = s.First().Ticket,
    Monday = s.Sum(c => c.Monday),
    Tuesday = s.Sum(c => c.Tuesday),
 });


class TicketTimes
{
    public string Ticket {get; set;}
    public float Monday {get; set;}
    public float Tuesday {get; set;}
}
```

Also see: [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Comment: I updated the original post. The times are stored in the standard DateTime format. So unless I can have LINQ group by Friendly day of the week I'm just as lost as before! Thank you for your post however.

Comment: You could try grouping by week number, e.g. currentDateTime.DayOfYear/7.

Comment: With your help I was able to figure it out. Thank you! Updated original post.

Comment: This is a vb question. Looks like c# to me.

Comment: @Mary: Yes, as mentioned above the example is in C# as I am not too familiar with VB.NET LINQ syntax. The code can be converted quite easily though.