# C# Entity Framework Grouping Sales By Hour

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, group-by

I have a class Order and OrderDetails with the following structure

```
public class Order 
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   ........
}
public class OrderDetails
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int TotalSales {get;set;}
   public DateTime OrderDate { get;set;}
   public int OrderId // navigation property to Order class
   ......
}
```

I need to sum the sales and group them by Hour and number of Order made at  this hour 
In other words I need the out to be like this

```
    {
       "date":"10-11-2018",
       "Hour":"9:00 AM",
       "totalSales":228.91,
       "OrdersCount":10
    },


    {
       "date":"10-11-2018",
       "Hour":"10:00 AM",
       "totalSales":150.8,
       "OrdersCount":5
    },
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is this related to SQL Server?

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Comment: Looks like this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522841/2799848

Comment: Sql server code will also do the job as i will use it as store procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can probably be optimized but it'll do what you're asking for

```
public class OrderCollectionDetails
{
    public DateTime ForDate { get; set; }
    public double TotalSales { get; set; }
    public int OrderCount { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetails
{
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public double Sales { get; set; }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<OrderDetails> orders = new List<OrderDetails>();
        orders.Add(new OrderDetails() { OrderDate  = DateTime.Parse("12/14/2018 3:00"), Sales = 10 });
        orders.Add(new OrderDetails() { OrderDate  = DateTime.Parse("12/14/2018 3:30"), Sales = 20.5 });
        orders.Add(new OrderDetails() { OrderDate  = DateTime.Parse("12/14/2018 3:40"), Sales = 55.23 });
        orders.Add(new OrderDetails() { OrderDate = DateTime.Parse("12/14/2018 4:00"), Sales = 1.11 });
        var orderGrp = orders.GroupBy(o => new DateTime(o.OrderDate.Year, o.OrderDate.Month, o.OrderDate.Day, o.OrderDate.Hour, 0, 0));
        List<OrderCollectionDetails> details = new List<OrderCollectionDetails>();
        foreach(var grp in orderGrp)
        {
            var firstItm = grp.FirstOrDefault();
            var targetDate = new DateTime(firstItm.OrderDate.Year, firstItm.OrderDate.Month, firstItm.OrderDate.Day, firstItm.OrderDate.Hour, 0, 0);
            details.Add(new OrderCollectionDetails()
            {
                ForDate = targetDate,
                OrderCount = grp.Count(),
                TotalSales = grp.Sum(g => g.Sales)
            });
        }
    }
```