# List of 2 elements (item & quantity), Issues getting SUM in the GroupBy

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a list of 2 items, model and qty. I am trying to get the sum of qty using Linq but am getting the following error at ModelList.Add(item.qty);
"cannot convert from int to string.
I need it to be an integer in order to get the Sum in the GroupBy statement below. What am I doing wrong?

[{"sector": "3","position": "3","qty": "1","model": "SBNHH-1D65C"
},{"sector": "1","position": "4","qty": "3","model": "SDFVR-U34R"}]

```
namespace Antenna
{
    public static class Rfds
    {
        public class Antenna
        {
            public AntennaItems[] root { get; set; }
        }
        public class AntennaItems
        {
            public int sector { get; set; }
            public int position { get; set; }
            public int qty { get; set; }
            public string model { get; set; }
        }

[FunctionName("AntennaSort")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

var jsonexample = requestBody;

var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AntennaItems>>(requestBody);

List<string> ModelList = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in jsonObj)
{
    if (item.model != "" && item.model != null)
    {
     ModelList.Add(item.model);
     ModelList.Add(item.qty);
     }
}

var ModelAndCount = ModelList.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum());
//var ModelAndCount = ModelList.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

return new OkObjectResult(ModelAndCount);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code for `AntennaItems` class

Comment: @Fabjan, 2elment in the code block.

Comment: I suspect you could simplify this code down in terms of making this a [mcve]. e.g. remove the `streamReader` and just have the JSON value defined in a string constant. _The key here is to make it such that we can copy and paste it into a console app and just run it - it should be completely standalone._

Comment: Well ModelList is a list of strings and item.qty is an int. Do you perhaps want `ModelList.Add(item.qty.ToString());`? Although that seems a little suspect.

Comment: What do you expect from ModelAndCount ? You what a sum of quatity per model? the number of time a model apears?

Comment: I will post all the code shortly.

Comment: I can change qty to a string but then I get an error at g.Sum()

Comment: Why is `ModelList` a `List<string>` and not a `List<ModelList>`?

Comment: ModelAndCount should be a list of models with the sum of all quantities.per model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue lies here

```
 ModelList.Add(item.qty);
```

Qty is an int and you are trying to add it to String Collection.Considering your eventual goal is to create the ModelAndCount Dictionary, you can directly query the jsonObj Collection, instead of creating an intermediate collection and then querying it.

Assuming that you want to Group By Model, You can do following

```
var ModelAndCount = jsonObj.Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.model))
                           .GroupBy(x=>x.model)
                           .ToDictionary(k=>k.Key,v=>v.Sum(x=>x.qty));
```

Output

[image]

Comment: That did it. I just had to change qty to allow null values and it's working great!Thanks everyone for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code that will `GroupBy` the data per model an `Sum` the quantity. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count).

Instead of creating an empty list then going into `foreach` to check the model value. We can simply filter them using LinQ `Where` clause and `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Then with a simple group we can compute the Sum. Here the result will be in a anonymous class.

```
public static void Run()
{
    //Data Initilisation
    var data = new[] {
        new DataItem{ model="a" , qty=1},
        new DataItem{ model="a" , qty=41},
        new DataItem{ model="b" , qty=12},
        new DataItem{ model="c" , qty=17},
    };
    var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);


    // Process
    var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataItem>>(jsonData);

    var result = jsonObj.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.model))
                        .GroupBy(x => x.model)
                        .Select(x => new { model = x.Key, sum = x.Sum(y => y.qty) })
                        .ToList();


}

public class DataItem
{
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

```
model: a               sum: 42
model: b               sum: 12
model: c               sum: 17
```