# Linq that Aggregates distinct IDs

Tags: c#, linq, linq-query-syntax

I am having trouble getting the correct Linq query for the following issue:
I have a List<> of storypoints that contains the following data:

```
ParentID    TaskID      Points
--------    ------    -----------
    1         100          2
    1         101          1
    1         103          1
    2         102          1
    2         104          4
    3         105          1
```

I'm looking to get a list of distinct ParentIDs with an Aggregate count of StoryPoints:

```
ParentID    Count
--------    -----
   1          4
   2          5
   3          1
```

I've tried this block but the syntax is throwing an error:

```
var storytaskpoints =
                        from u in storypoints
                        group u by u.ParentID into g
                        select new
                        {
                            ParentID = g.Key,
                            Count = (from u in g select u.Points).Count();
                        }
```

My Class for StoryTaskPoint:

```
class StoryTaskPoint
    {
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public int Points { get; set; }
        public int TaskID { get; set; }

        public StoryTaskPoint()
        { }

        StoryTaskPoint(
            int taskID,
            int parentID,
            int points)
        {
            TaskID = taskID;
            ParentID = parentID;
            Points = points;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Pay **utmost** attention to the error message(s) -- don't ignore them -- and where you (mis)placed the semicolon there in your Linq query. The error message you get (as well as Visual Studio's wiggly lines) will point this out to you. Also, `Count = (from u in g select u.Points).Count();` is not doing what you seem to believe it does. Check the documentation for the Linq method [`Count()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) to learn what it really does...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  Since you have an answer that worked, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the little green checkmark in the top-left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 from u in storypoints
                        group u by u.ParentID into g
                        select new
                        {
                            ParentID = g.Key,
                            Count = g.Sum(gg=>gg.Points)
                        }
```

Use `.Sum` instead of `.Count`