# Merge items in List<T> when particular values in list matches

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<Returns>` as below

```
Item    ManCode  ShippedQty
ITM01   A10         1
ITM02   A11         2
ITM01   A10         3
```

Here the first and `3` rd rows have same values for `Item` and `Mancode`. in this case, the both the items should be merged and `shippedQty` values must be added to `4`.
There should be only `2` items in the final list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Comment: You need to do this using `LINQ` or `SQL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Linq to group the objects on Item and ManCode and sum the quantity like this:

```
var data = new List<Element> 
{ 
  new Element{  Item ="ITM01", ManCode = "A10", ShippedQty = 1},
  new Element{  Item ="ITM02", ManCode = "A11", ShippedQty = 2},
  new Element{  Item ="ITM01", ManCode = "A10", ShippedQty = 3},
};

var datagrp = (from q in data
               group q by new { q.Item, q.ManCode } into p
               select new Element 
               { Item = p.Key.Item, ManCode = p.Key.ManCode, 
                 ShippedQty = p.Sum(s => s.ShippedQty)}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use linq `GroupBy` with `Sum` function.

```
list.GroupBy(x=> new{x.Item ,x.ManCode}).Select(
    x=> new {
        Item = x.key.Item,
        ManCode = x.key.ManCode,
        ShippedQty = x.Sum(y=>y.ShippedQty)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Item, x.ManCode })
                  .Select(x => new Returns 
                  { 
                      Item = x.Key.Item, 
                      ManCode = x.Key.ManCode, 
                      ShippedQty = x.Sum(y => y.ShippedQty)
                  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
List<Returns> list = new List<Returns>(){ /*populate list here*/ };
list = list
         .GroupBy(i => new {i.Item, i.ManCode})
         .Select(g => new {g.Key.Item, g.Key.ManCode, g.Sum(i => i.ShippedQty)} );
```