# Show duplicates from lists c#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, linq

I'm working on a WPF application, and at one point, I have to get/show all the duplicates from the string list. (With the duplicated strings name and the number of how many of that same string is in the list)Like this for example: "The list contains the String 'Hello' 3 times." So far, I'm getting the string's name successfully but I can't manage to get the correct number of times it is presented in the list.
This is my code so far:

```
List<String> answerData = new List<String>();

using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query2, conn))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            answerData.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                        }
                    }
                }

var duplicates = answerData
                .GroupBy(i => i)
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .Select(g => g.Key);

foreach (var d in duplicates)
{           
    MessageBox.Show(""+ d + duplicates.Count().ToString()); //Here I tried to get the number
    //with Count() but it doesn't work as I thought it would. 

}
```

What should I add/change to get the result I want?

**EDIT**

As suggested changed my code to the following:

```
var duplicates = answerData
                .GroupBy(i => i)
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);

foreach (var d in duplicates)
{
  MessageBox.Show(d.Key + " " + d.Count().ToString());
}
```

And now it works smoothly. 
Thank you everyone!

Comment: You are only selecting the key as a return. Remove the last `Select`

Comment: `.Select(g => g.Key)` You have selected only the key. If you want the count you should get it `new {g.Key g.Count()}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Comment: .Select(g => new {key = g.Key, count = g.Count()}).ToList();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the actual groups instead of the keys in `duplicates`:

```
var duplicates = answerData
            .GroupBy(i => i)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

You could then iterate through the groups:

```
foreach (var d in duplicates)
{           
    MessageBox.Show(d.Key + " " + d.Count().ToString());
}
```

This example counts, i.e. iterates, each group twice. Alternatively, you could store objects that contain both the `Key` and the `Count` as suggested by @HimBromBeere.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to return the number within your `Select`:

```
var duplicates = answerData
            .GroupBy(i => i)
            .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = x.Count() })
            .Where(x => x.Count > 1);
```

Notice that I changed the order of your statements to avoid a duplicate execution of `g.Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this
you need to use Dictionary for performance reasons

```
            List<String> answerData = new List<String>();

        Dictionary<string,int> map = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var data in answerData)
        {
            if (map.ContainsKey(data))
            {
                map[data]++;
            }
            else
            {
                map.Add(data, 1);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in map)
        {
            if (item.Value > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.Key, item.Value);

            }
        }
```