# How to GroupBy when retrieving data from OData API?

Tags: c#, linq, odata

I am retrieving data from OData API and projecting it into a different class:

```
            data = context.Product.Where(p => p.name == name)
                                             .Take(10)
                                             .Select(p => new MyCustomProduct
                                             {
                                                 id = p.id,                                                 
                                                 year = p.year,
                                                 amount = p.amount,                                                 
                                                 customProperty = 00
                                             });
```

This works fine. However, I also need a function to group the retrieved products by year, and calculate the total amount of products for each year. How is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First group your result by year, then calc the sum for each year:

```
var data = context.Product.Where(p => p.name == name)
                      .Take(10)
                      .GroupBy(p => p.year)
                      .Select(group => new { year = group.Key, sum = group.Sum(p => p.amount) })
                      .ToList();
```

your data variable then is `List<a'>` where `a' = { int year, int sum }`

Comment: Grouping first will give OData the chance to simplify the service call.

Comment: yes, you are right. I completely removed the first `Select()` which is unnecessary.

Comment: I know it's a noob question, but thanks for helping.