# How to compare similarities in two csv files

Tags: c#, collections

I am new to the C# programming and I'm working on a Report type project. I have two CSV files, owners and vehicles, that both have an ownerID within them. I want to output a list of owners and for each owner a list of all vehicles owned, then each vehicle should list: year, make, model and mileage and at the end a line reading "Owner Id..... n cars" (replace 'n' with the count').

```cs
foreach (Owner o in own2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t", o.oID, o.oFirst, o.oLast);
    for (Vehicle v in cars2)
    {
        //v.oID == o.oID, Console.WriteLine (year, make, model, milage)
    }
}
```

I know I have the list of the owners, but I do not know how to connect the vehicles with the same ownerID attached to them.

Comment: Hi perhaps use a LINQ query (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245061/how-to-compare-similarities-in-two-csv-files)

Comment: Class definition of `Owner`, and `Vehicle`. Simple list declaration and initialisation to represent 2-3 owner and  vehicule, it will be the input . And the expected output. You may be looking for a simple Groupby and count like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no sufficient details in your post, but probably you want something like this below:

```
foreach (Owner o in own2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t", o.oID, o.oFirst, o.oLast);

    int n = 0;
    for (Vehicle v in cars2.Where(car => car.oID == o.oID))
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}",v.year, v.make, v.model, v.milage);
        n++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("User owns: {0} cars", n);
}
```