# Count elements of an array only using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the 3 classes `Item`, `Order` and `Management`.
`Order` has an array with `ordered Items`, `Managemen`t has a `List of different Orders`. How can I display the number of ordered items for all `PurchaseOrders` with the given name?

**For example:** Item1 is ordered 2 times with quantity = 5 and 2 times with quantity = 7, so the total number is 2*5+2*7=24.

I can solve the task, but only Linq should be used without loops, etc.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Management Management = new Management();
        Management.PrintQuantityForSingleItem("Item1");
    }
}

class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Item(string Name, decimal Price, int Quantity)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Price = Price;
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
    }
}

class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }

    public Order(int Id, Item[] Items)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Items = Items;
    }
}

class Management
{
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public Management()
    {
        Item i1 = new Item("Item1", 2.0M, 5);
        Item i2 = new Item("Item2", 3.0M, 6);
        Item i3 = new Item("Item1", 2.0M, 7);

        Orders = new List<Order>()
        {
            new Order(1, new Item[]{i1, i2}),
            new Order(2, new Item[]{i3}),
            new Order(3, new Item[]{i1, i3}),
        };
    }

    //displays the total number of ordered items for all Orders with the given name on the console.
    public void PrintQuantityForSingleItem(string itemName)
    {
        var result = (from x in Orders
                      select x.Items).ToList();

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < result[i].Count(); a++)
            {
                if (result[i][a].Name == itemName)
                {
                    counter = counter + result[i][a].Quantity;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(result[i][a].Name);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(itemName + " " + counter);//for example: shows 24 for item1
    }
}
```

Comment: group by + sum? where is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Comment: You can find a description of the various LINQ operators [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/standard-query-operators-overview).
Each description comes with various examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. It is obviously not advisable to look up items by name, but ignoring aspects of the design, here is one way of doing it:

```
var result = Orders.SelectMany(i => i.Items)
    .Where(i => i.Name == itemName)
    .Sum(i => i.Quantity);

Console.WriteLine($"{itemName}: {result}"); //24
```

Output:

> Item1: 24

Comment: Your solution helps me a lot, I changed it to query syntax and it works:)

Comment: @VanillaBigThundr I am glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to select all order items, group them by name and then calculate the sum value for the `Quantity`. The final step is to get the calculated sum value by item name and display it

```cs
public void PrintQuantityForSingleItem(string itemName)
{
    var results = Orders
        .SelectMany(o => o.Items)
        .GroupBy(i => i.Name)
        .Select(g => new { Item = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(i => i.Quantity) });

    var item = results.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Item.Equals(itemName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    Console.WriteLine(itemName + " " + item?.Sum);//shows 24 for item1
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but I'm not a fan of using underscore like this as it usually means the parameter is going to be ignored.

Comment: @juharr IMO, it's just for simplicity:) I can update the code, of course

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq :

```
decimal counter = Orders
    .SelectMany(o => o.Items)
    .Where(i => i.Name == itemName)
    .Sum(i => i.Quantity);
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: The `Distinct` is not needed and will cause the result to be wrong since the OP is reusing the same `Item` objects in multiple `Order` lists.  Also they wanted the `Quantity`, not the total price.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following,

```
public void PrintQuantityForSingleItem(string itemName)
    {
        var res = Orders.Select(x=>x.Items).Sum(y => y.Where(z => z.Name == itemName).Sum(t => t.Quantity));
        Console.WriteLine(res);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

> It prints 24

Comment: The OP himself has stated the result should be 24. Also, The method needs to return quantity (as stated on its name), not total.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but you don't have to multiply price and quantity, just sum a quantity

Comment: I withdrew my downvote after you updated your answer. However, The code is still inefficient. Linq has methods that combine some of these operations. See my answer below.

Comment: thank you @JuanR , i consider your answer. i am afk , i will try your answer as soons as possible. At the moment, voted you