# Aggregating list items by 2 properties and summing the 3rd in C#

Tags: c#, list, console-application

I have a list of objects `LoggedRestarts` with three properties: `Release`, `Build` and `NumberOfRestarts`. The first two contain many duplicates which might have different values for the third property. I want to aggregate these into one and sum the `NumberOfRestarts`; quite the equivalent of what I've written in python: `df = df.groupby(['Release','Build'], as_index=False)['NumberOfRestarts'].sum()`.

Say I have these objects of type `LoggedRestarts` in my list:

```
    Release-----------------Build---------------NumberOfRestarts
(1) 12.21------------------Build1---------------1
(2) 12.21------------------Build1---------------2
```

I want it to become like this:

```
    Release-----------------Build---------------NumberOfRestarts
(1) 12.21------------------Build1---------------3
```

Currently I have the following code, which is not really of use as there are still values left unaggregated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < loggedRestartsList.Count; i++)
     {
        if (loggedRestartsList[i].release == loggedRestartsList[i + 1].release
            & loggedRestartsList[i].build == loggedRestartsList[i + 1].build)
        {
           loggedRestartsList[i+1].numberOfRestarts = loggedRestartsList[i].numberOfRestarts + loggedRestartsList[i + 1].numberOfRestarts;
           loggedRestartsList.RemoveAt(i);
        }
     }
```

I have also found a solution like this: [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count) but I couldn't work my head around it.

Therefore, how could I accomplish the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `GroupBy`:

```
List<(string Release, string Build, int NumberOfRestarts)> releaseBuildGroups = loggedRestartsList
    .GroupBy(x => (x.Release, x.Build))
    .Select(g => (g.Key.Release, g.Key.Build, g.Sum(x => x.NumberOfRestarts)))
    .ToList();
```

Instead of using a ValueTuple you could also initialize new instances of your class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I get an error saying `LoggedRestarts does not contain a definition for GroupBy`. I've also tried `using System.Linq` with no luck. How can I fix it? What am I missing out?

Comment: `LoggedRestarts` is an object.

Comment: @Arthur777: ah ok, then you should probably use `loggedRestartsList` ;-)

Comment: Oh, I see, now. I changed `LoggedRestarts` to `loggedRestartsList`, which is a list containing the objects and now I will start debugging. But overall I can understand what's the process. Thank you a lot, once again!