# How to sum a column id datagridview?

Tags: c#

I apologize for not writing any code, I just put this example to explain what is required, all I want is to sum values from the column "Oil_Qt" for each "Fix_No" so that the result is as shown in the three lines below:

| ID | Fix_No | Fix_Name | Car_Number | Oil_Qt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Change Engine Oil | 77 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 | Change Gearbox Oil | 60 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | Change Gearbox Oil | 30 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 | Change Hydraulic Oil | 80 | 32 |
| 5 | 1 | Change Engine Oil | 80 | 15 |
| 6 | 1 | Change Engine Oil | 50 | 18 |
| 7 | 3 | Change Hydraulic Oil | 35 | 10 |
| 8 | 1 | Change Engine Oil | 35 | 15 |

Sum of Engine Oil = 68
Sum of Gearbox Oil = 10
Sum of Hydraulic Oil = 42
I tried this code but it didn't work:

````
            for (int i = 0; i < dgOils.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgOils.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
            }
            txtEngineOils.Text = sum.ToString();```
````

Comment: Why have you not written any code? Have you made any attempt yet? You need to show *some* effort and demonstrate the issue you're having, not simply outline a task you need to complete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Answer (score 0):

```
var gridDataSource = (DataTable)[YourDataGridView].Datasource;
var sumEngineOil = gridDataSource.Compute("Sum[Oil_Qt]", "[Fix_No]=1");
var sumGearboxOil = gridDataSource.Compute("Sum[Oil_Qt]", "[Fix_No]=2");
var sumHydraulicOil = gridDataSource.Compute("Sum[Oil_Qt]", "[Fix_No]=3");
```