# Group by results in ling

Tags: c#, linq

I have linq statement that returns value.  The LINQ statement below will returns the systemUser Id and totalHours of a systemUser as shown below.  However,  what I really what is to get the Id and the total hours per system user. How to add group then in linq?

```
var th1 = (from ss in db.SystemUsers
    join t in db.Timesheets on ss.Id equals t.SystemUser
    where (t.Project == projectId && t.StartTime >= year_start && t.StartTime < year_end)
    select new
    {
        ss.Id,
        t.TotalHours
    });
```

---

```
 Id     |   TotalHours
  1     |     10
  1     |     20
  2     |     10
  2     |     5 
 and so on...
```

---

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
 Id     |   TotalHours
  1     |     30
  2     |     15
 and so on...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Comment: Nope I have joined two tables in my part and I should not also need to create a new object for the returned values.  I know there must be a way to do it. But I just don't know it.

Comment: Off the top of my head   before your `select new` group your data `group ss by ss.ID into grouppeddata` then in your select new it becomes `ID=grouppeddata.Key,TotalHours=grouppeddata.Sum(g =>g.TotalHours)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `GroupBy`

```cs
var th1 = 
    from ss in db.SystemUsers
    join t in db.Timesheets on ss.Id equals t.SystemUser
    where (t.Project == projectId && t.StartTime >= year_start && t.StartTime < year_end)
    group t by new { ss.Id } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.Id,
        TotalHours = g.Sum(x => x.TotalHours)
    };
```