# groupby in dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures

`var dict = new Dictionary<ClassA,int>();`

I should add the Name and Seat number into the dict but I have to take it from separate classes,
eg

```
dict.Add(student.name)
dict.Add(class.studentlist.score)
```

I want it to get an output of

```
Student   Score
Amy       78
Amy       89
Amy       45
Ben       34
.
.
.
```

as well as one that shows the total score if the student's name repeats more than once

```
Student   Score
Amy       (total score)
Ben       (total score)
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this, or if it is even possible? The name and score comes from different classes so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? it it building a dictionary of key (Student ) and (score) value?

Comment: You cannot have a dictionary with multiple `"Amy"` keys: the keys are unique in  a dictionary.

Comment: You can not do it with dictionary at all, since it has a key, but you are repeating the names.

Comment: @BartKiers should I use a list instead then? but how do I try and group it together afterwards?

Comment: @AmjadSaab yes, I can't seem to group it too

Comment: Use a `List` and then do `GroupBy` and `Sum` on the `Student` column. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count

Comment: No overload of Dictionary.Add accepts one argument

Comment: Your data modelling has gone wonky. What you *really, actually* should have is a Student class that has a List<int> inside it to hold the scores associated *with that student*. You can then keep your students in a list, and each student hs a list of int scores.

Comment: @CaiusJard Or name the student class `StudentGrade`

Comment: Mmm perhaps.. But to me that would be a class that connects a Student and a (single) Grade, like a linking entity decomposing a M:M relationship.. It's (for me) reasonable to stop at Student and a Student has-a list of grades; though you bring about another point that there are multiple aspects to a Grade that we might want to model, beyond the raw score - like what paper was it in? What was the A/B+ etc result etc, so maybe a Student would has-a List<Grade> .. ah.. choices choices, and of course we could step into that if there was a need to model to that level of detail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a dictionary with multiple  Name keys, name should be unigue. So try to create a list

```
var students = new List<Student>();

    students.Add(new Student { Name = "Amy", Score = 78 });
    students.Add(new Student { Name = "Ben", Score = 34 });
    students.Add(new Student { Name = "Amy", Score = 89 });
    students.Add(new Student { Name = "Amy", Score = 45 });

List<string,int> scores = students.GroupBy(s => s.Name)
    .Select(i => new Student { Name = i.Key, Score = i.Sum(x => x.Score) }).ToList();

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE

@Cleptus suggested to use a Dictionary<string, List> where string is a name, and list is to keep the score. It is a very interesting idea, but I  like more a list, since it is more like an relational db and linq is ideal for list collections. I feel Dictionaries as too hierarchical , and the always need an extra step or  code to get some information.

but dictionary could be used to keep the result information

```
 Dictionary<string, int> result = students.GroupBy(s => s.Name)
.ToDictionary( i => i.Key, i=> i.Sum(x => x.Score));
  
 var amyResult=result["Amy"];
```

Comment: Also a `Dictionary<Student, List<int>>` would work and keep a solution with a key. Or a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` where the key would be the student's name.

Comment: @Cleptus It is a very interesting idea, but I can not see what we gain here. it will need more complicated code to check if value exist, but in the end you will have to create a query to count a sum in any case. I prefer a list since it is more relational, you can always use linq to count any information.

Comment: *I like more a list, since it is more like an relational db and linq is ideal for list collections* - that's slightly unusual reasoning; to me a database [table] is more like a dictionary: dictionary has key that uniquely identifies a bunch of associated data. Database table has primary key that uniquely identifies a row of data.. LINQ is ideal for any enumerable thing, really.. like a list, or indeed a dictionary!  (though the true power of a dictionary is in lookups; the reasons for choosing List, array, LinkedList, HashSet, Dictionary etc should be driven by what we need them to do..)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class student is:

```cs
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You could use a `Dictionary` whose key would be a `Student` and whose content would be a list/array of scores.

```cs
List<Student, List<int>> results = new List<Student, List<int>>();
results.Add(new Student() { Name = "Amy"}, new List<int>() { 78, 89, 45 });
results.Add(new Student() { Name = "Ben"}, new List<int>() { 61 });
```

And to show the data, you just need to iterate the keys and show the data however you need (either aggregated or individually).

```cs
using System.Linq;
....

foreach (Student currentStudent in results.Keys) {
    List<int> studentResults = results[currentStudent];
    
    // This would show your first needed output (individual scores)
    foreach(int result in studentResults) Console.WriteLine(currentStudent.Name + ": " + result.ToString());

    // This would show your second needed output (total scores)
    Console.WriteLine(currentStudent.Name + ": " + studentResults.Sum().ToString());
}
```

The second one takes advantage of [IEnumerable.Sum()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-sum(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-int32))))